# How to design Entity Relationship that match Relationship Model?

Tags: database, object, relational-database, entity-relationship

Hello everyone and first of all thank you for all of those who take time to read my question and replying.

I have a RM that I need to design a ER that match to it.

the RM:
A(c,j) // c is underlined
B(b,c,d,e,h) // b,c,d,h is underlined
C(a,g,h,i) // h is underlined
D(c,f,g,i) // c,i is underlined

I thought about the following ER (I am describing it as I cant really draw it here):
Entity "A" with attributes: "c"(key), "j"
Entity "B" with attributes: "b"(key),"d"(key), "e"
Entity "C" with attributes: "h"(key), "a", "g"
Entity "D" with attributes: "i"(key), "f", "g" (different from attribute of C)

the relationships:
A-B (many-many)
A-D
B-C
C->D (many-one)

is that correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your ER interpretation is influenced by diagramming tool terminology, which unfortunately has little to do with the ER model as described by Chen.  Many diagramming tools use entity to mean table, attribute to mean column, and relationship to mean foreign key constraint, serving only to confuse and mislead users.

Entities in ER are values which are the subject of attributes or relationships.  The entities in your RM would be `b`, `c`, `d`, `h` and `i`.  Your relations `A` and `C` are called entity relations.  For reference, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, `g`, `h` and `i` are called domains, or sets of values.

Attributes in ER are binary relations on entities; in your case they would be `c->j`, `h->a`, `h->g`, and `h->i`.

Higher order relations are called relationships, these would be `b,c,d,h` and `c,i`.  These relationships are themselves attributed: `b,c,d,h->e` and `c,i->f,g`.  Your relations `B` and `D` are called relationship relations.

Foreign key constraints can't be inferred without understanding the business logic of the model.  It's tempting to assume a constraint from `A.c to B.c`, for example, but how do we know A is [left-total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations) (i.e. that all instances of c are recorded in it)?  If the model is complete (not part of a larger model) and we assume a [closed world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption), then we can infer constraints from `A.c to D.c`, `A.c to B.c` and `C.h to B.h`.

Compare an ERD in Chen's notation:

[image: ER diagram]

with what is called an ERD these days:

[image: Table diagram]

Chen's notation properly distinguishes entities (rectangles), attributes (ovals) and relationships (diamonds) including reified relationships (aka associative entities `B` and `D`).  The second diagram should really be called a table diagram instead of an ER diagram, as it represents tables, columns and foreign key constraints.

Comment: Hi Reenb, Thank you for your reply. it was very useful.

Comment: @JonBrice If you think it's useful and do solve your problem. Please upvote or accept the answer. This is how our community works.